# MATLAB Numpy element wise multiplication issue

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Please see the MATLAB code and equivalent Numpy code below. 
Question: How can I get the D variable same in Numpy as MATLAB's?

**MATLAB Code**

```matlab
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

C = [100 1; 10 0.1; 1, 0.01]

C = reshape(C, 1,3,2)

D = bsxfun(@times, A, C)

D(:,:,1) =

       100    20     3
       400    50     6
       700    80     9

D(:,:,2) =

    1.0000    0.2000    0.0300
    4.0000    0.5000    0.0600
    7.0000    0.8000    0.0900
```

**Numpy Code**

```py
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

C = np.array([[[100, 1], [10, 0.1], [1, 0.01]]]) # C.shape is (1, 3, 2)

D = A * C.T

D

    array([[[100.  , 200.  , 300.  ],
            [ 40.  ,  50.  ,  60.  ],
            [  7.  ,   8.  ,   9.  ]],

           [[  1.  ,   2.  ,   3.  ],
            [  0.4 ,   0.5 ,   0.6 ],
            [  0.07,   0.08,   0.09]]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You can do this by multiplying the transposes of the matrices and then transposing the final sub matrices using swapaxes

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
C = np.array([[[100, 1], [10, 0.1], [1, 0.01]]]) # C.shape is (1, 3, 2)

D = (A.T*C.T)
D = D.swapaxes(1,2)
```

You can also combine these lines as

```
D = (A.T*C.T).swapaxes(1,2)
```

---

**Output**

```
array([[[1.e+02, 2.e+01, 3.e+00],
    [4.e+02, 5.e+01, 6.e+00],
    [7.e+02, 8.e+01, 9.e+00]],

   [[1.e+00, 2.e-01, 3.e-02],
    [4.e+00, 5.e-01, 6.e-02],
    [7.e+00, 8.e-01, 9.e-02]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You added a transpose to `C` which is not present in the MATLAB code.

If you want to keep the exact same data layout, inject a *trailing* singleton dimension into `A`. In MATLAB *trailing* singletons are implicit, in numpy *leading* singletons are implicit:

```
>>> D = A[...,None] * C.squeeze()

>>> D
array([[[1.e+02, 1.e+00],
        [2.e+01, 2.e-01],
        [3.e+00, 3.e-02]],

       [[4.e+02, 4.e+00],
        [5.e+01, 5.e-01],
        [6.e+00, 6.e-02]],

       [[7.e+02, 7.e+00],
        [8.e+01, 8.e-01],
        [9.e+00, 9.e-02]]])
```

Here `A[..., None]` has shape `(3, 3, 1)` and `C.squeeze()` just undoes that superfluous leading singleton dimension and makes it shape `(3,2)` These broadcast to shape `(3, 3, 2)`. MATLAB and numpy interpret multidimensional arrays differently, which explains why the `repr` above corresponds to three arrays of shape `(3,2)` whereas MATLAB shows you two arrays of shape `(3,3`). But really it's the same array:

```
>>> D[..., 0]
array([[100.,  20.,   3.],
       [400.,  50.,   6.],
       [700.,  80.,   9.]])

>>> D[..., 1]
array([[1.  , 0.2 , 0.03],
       [4.  , 0.5 , 0.06],
       [7.  , 0.8 , 0.09]])
```

Note that if you keep the MATLAB order in your numpy code you might want to use fortran layout in your arrays, otherwise you'll have "fast" axes in suboptimal places in the numpy code.